# boost::shared_ptr error

Tags: c++, boost

```
class EntityHolder {
public:

    EntityHolder ( ) { }

    EntityHolder (
            const EntityHolder& other )  { }
    ~EntityHolder ( ) { }

    EntityHolder&
    operator = (
            const EntityHolder& other ) {
        return *this;
    } // =
```

When I am trying to create boost:shared_ptr, I get the following error:

```
..\src\Entity.cpp:7:34: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::shared_ptr<orm::EntityHolder>::shared_ptr (orm::EntityHolder&)'
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You should post the line in which you're trying to make the `shared_ptr`, i.e. the line that gives the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to pass an object of type `EntityHolder` directly to the constructor of the `shared_ptr`, but you're supposed to give it a pointer, like so:

```
boost::shared_ptr<EntityHolder> p(new EntityHolder);
```